# How to test that a model was used in a FastAPI route?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest, fastapi

I'm trying to check if a specific model was used as an input parser for a FastAPI route. However, I'm not sure how to patch (or spy on) it.

I have the following file structure:

```
.
└── roo
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── main.py
    └── test_demo.py
```

main.py:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

class ItemModel(BaseModel):
    name: str

@app.post("/")
async def read_main(item: ItemModel):
    return {"msg": f"Item: {item.name}"}
```

test_demo.py:

```
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from unittest.mock import patch
from roo.main import app, ItemModel

client = TestClient(app)

def test_can_creating_new_item_users_proper_validation_model():
    with patch('roo.main.ItemModel', wraps=ItemModel) as patched_model:
        response = client.post("/", json={'name': 'good'})
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {"msg": "Item: good"}
    assert patched_model.called
```

However, `patched_model` is never called (other asserts pass). I don't want to change the functionality or replace `ItemModel` in main.py, I just want to check if it was used.

Answer (score 2):

My first approach to this was to wrap the `read_main` method and check that the `item` passed into the function is *indeed* an instance of `ItemModel`. But that was a dead-end approach because of the way FastAPI endpoints are prepared and stored: FastAPI stores a copy of the endpoint function objects in a list: (see [fastapi/routing.py](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/master/fastapi/routing.py)), then evaluates at request-time which endpoint to call.

```py
from roo.main import app

def test_read_main():
    assert 'read_main' in [r.endpoint.__name__ for r in app.routes]

    # check that read_main was called *and* received an ItemModel instance?
```

My second approach involves spying or "breaking" the initialization of `ItemModel`, such that if the endpoint does *indeed* use that model, then a "broken" `ItemModel` would cause a request that hits that endpoint to fail. We "break" `ItemModel` by making use of the fact that (1) FastAPI calls the `__init__` of your model during the request-response cycle, and (2) a 422 error response is propagated by default when the endpoint is unable to serialize a model properly:

```py
class ItemModel(BaseModel):
    name: str

    def __init__(__pydantic_self__, **data: Any) -> None:
        print("Make a POST request and confirm that this is printed out")
        super().__init__(**data)
```

So in tests, just mock the `__init__` method:

- Example for pytest

  ```
  import pytest
  from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
  from roo.main import app, ItemModel

  def test_read_main(monkeypatch: pytest.MonkeyPatch):
      client = TestClient(app)

      def broken_init(self, **data):
          pass  # `name` and other fields won't be set

      monkeypatch.setattr(ItemModel, '__init__', broken_init)
      with pytest.raises(AttributeError) as exc:
          client.post("/", json={'name': 'good'})
          assert 422 == response.status_code
      assert "'ItemModel' object has no attribute" in str(exc.value)
  ```
- Example for pytest + [pytest-mock](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-mock)'s [`mocker.spy`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-mock#spy)

  ```
  from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
  from pytest_mock import MockerFixture
  from roo.main import app, ItemModel

  def test_read_main(mocker: MockerFixture):
      client = TestClient(app)
      spy = mocker.spy(ItemModel, '__init__')

      client.post("/", json={'name': 'good'})
      spy.assert_called()
      spy.assert_called_with(**{'name': 'good'})
  ```
- Example for unittest

  ```
  from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
  from roo.main import app, ItemModel
  from unittest.mock import patch

  def test_read_main():
      client = TestClient(app)

      # Wrapping __init__ like this isn't really correct, but serves the purpose
      with patch.object(ItemModel, '__init__', wraps=ItemModel.__init__) as mocked_init:
          response = client.post("/", json={'name': 'good'})
          assert 422 == response.status_code
          mocked_init.assert_called()
          mocked_init.assert_called_with(**{'name': 'good'})
  ```

Again, the tests check that the endpoint fails in either serializing into an `ItemModel` or in accessing `item.name`, which will only happen if the endpoint is *indeed* using `ItemModel`.

If you modify the endpoint from `item: ItemModel` into `item: OtherModel`:

```
class OtherModel(BaseModel):
    name: str

class ItemModel(BaseModel):
    name: str

@app.post("/")
async def read_main(item: OtherModel):  # <----
    return {"msg": f"Item: {item.name}"}
```

then running the tests should now fail because the endpoint is now creating the wrong object:

```
    def test_read_main(mocker: MockerFixture):
        client = TestClient(app)
        spy = mocker.spy(ItemModel, '__init__')
    
        client.post("/", json={'name': 'good'})
>       spy.assert_called()
E       AssertionError: Expected '__init__' to have been called.

test_demo_spy.py:11: AssertionError

        with pytest.raises(AttributeError) as exc:
            response = client.post("/", json={'name': 'good'})
>           assert 422 == response.status_code
E           assert 422 == 200
E             +422
E             -200

test_demo_pytest.py:15: AssertionError
```

The assertion errors for 422 == 200 is a bit confusing, but it basically means that even though we "broke" `ItemModel`, we still got a 200/OK response.. which means `ItemModel` is not being used.

Likewise, if you modified the tests first and mocked-out the `__init__` of `OtherModel` instead of `ItemModel`, then running the tests without modifying the endpoint will result in similar failing tests:

```
    def test_read_main(mocker: MockerFixture):
        client = TestClient(app)
        spy = mocker.spy(OtherModel, '__init__')
    
        client.post("/", json={'name': 'good'})
>       spy.assert_called()
E       AssertionError: Expected '__init__' to have been called.

    def test_read_main():
        client = TestClient(app)
    
        with patch.object(OtherModel, '__init__', wraps=OtherModel.__init__) as mocked_init:
            response = client.post("/", json={'name': 'good'})
            # assert 422 == response.status_code
    
>           mocked_init.assert_called()
E           AssertionError: Expected '__init__' to have been called.
```

The assertion here is less confusing because it says we expected that the endpoint will call `OtherModel`'s `__init__`, but it wasn't called. It should pass after modifying the endpoint to use `item: OtherModel`.

One last thing to note is that since we are manipulating the `__init__`, then it can cause the "happy path" to fail, so it should now be tested separately. Make sure to undo/revert the mocks and patches:

- Example for pytest

  ```
  def test_read_main(monkeypatch: pytest.MonkeyPatch):
      client = TestClient(app)

      def broken_init(self, **data):
          pass

      # Are we really using ItemModel?
      monkeypatch.setattr(ItemModel, '__init__', broken_init)
      with pytest.raises(AttributeError) as exc:
          response = client.post("/", json={'name': 'good'})
          assert 422 == response.status_code
      assert "'ItemModel' object has no attribute" in str(exc.value)

      # Okay, really using ItemModel. Does it work correctly?
      monkeypatch.undo()
      response = client.post("/", json={'name': 'good'})
      assert response.status_code == 200
      assert response.json() == {"msg": "Item: good"}
  ```
- Example for pytest + [pytest-mock](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-mock)'s [`mocker.spy`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-mock#spy)

  ```
  from pytest_mock import MockerFixture
  from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
  from roo.main import app, ItemModel


  def test_read_main(mocker: MockerFixture):
      client = TestClient(app)

      # Are we really using ItemModel?
      spy = mocker.spy(ItemModel, '__init__')
      client.post("/", json={'name': 'good'})
      spy.assert_called()
      spy.assert_called_with(**{'name': 'good'})

      # Okay, really using ItemModel. Does it work correctly?
      mocker.stopall()
      response = client.post("/", json={'name': 'good'})
      assert response.status_code == 200
      assert response.json() == {"msg": "Item: good"}
  ```
- Example for unittest

  ```
  def test_read_main():
      client = TestClient(app)

      # Are we really using ItemModel?
      with patch.object(ItemModel, '__init__', wraps=ItemModel.__init__) as mocked_init:
          response = client.post("/", json={'name': 'good'})
          assert 422 == response.status_code
          mocked_init.assert_called()
          mocked_init.assert_called_with(**{'name': 'good'})

      # Okay, really using ItemModel. Does it work correctly?
      response = client.post("/", json={'name': 'good'})
      assert response.status_code == 200
      assert response.json() == {"msg": "Item: good"}
  ```

All in all, you might want to consider if/why it's useful to check for which model is exactly used. Normally, I just check that passing-in valid request params returns the expected valid response, and likewise, that invalid requests returns an error response.